# If no Avatar, check gender from json and place in img tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I build a app (its my first app) and there i give user the option to upload there user avatar and setup there genders. if (in this case a girl) dont upload any avatar, then i want to check the json and get the gender information, with this gender information i want to place the url to the female default avatar.

Here is my Controller Code:

```
$scope.getUserImage = function (user) {
    if (user.avatar) {
        return user.avatar;
    } else {
        return '/images/icons/user-' + user.gender + '.svg';
    }
};

$scope.schueler = [
    {
        firstName: 'Sven',
        lastName: 'Wauback',
        gender: 'male',
        avatar: 'url to avatar',
        notice: 'Fast fertig mit Theorie'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Sonja',
        lastName: 'Flockenbarsch',
        gender: 'female',
        avatar: 'url to avatar',
        notice: 'Brauch Praxis Extrastunden'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Lisa',
        lastName: 'Weber',
        gender: 'female',
        avatar: '',
        notice: 'Hat kein bock auf Fotoabgabe'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Manuel',
        lastName: 'Bürstenkrieger',
        gender: 'male',
        avatar: 'url to avatar',
        notice: 'Denkt er wär der coolste'
    }
];
```

And here the View File:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in schueler" class="md-2-line" ng-click="null">
    <img ng-src="getUserImage(user)" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}"/>
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
        <h3>{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</h3>
        <p>{{item.notice}}</p>
    </div>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

Ok the function at top is a first try from me.. but this dont work. i dont know much javascript. i think this snipped is complete wrong. Can anyone tell me how is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're passing in the wrong value for your image source. Shouldn't it be `getUserImage(item)` instead of `getUserImage(user)`

**Edit:** To get the value out it would be `ng-src="{{getUserImage(item)}}"`

Comment: but angular dont touch the getUserImage function. After loading the App in Browser, he still got this in Sourcecode: <img ng-src="getUserImage(item)" src="getUserImage(item)">

Comment: ohh great this works! =) i thinked functions dont need the {{ }}... Thanks alot!

Comment: @SvenBudak Glad to help :)